# HTML email does not appear as seen on its HTML file

Tags: php, email, html-email, sendgrid

Here's my PHP code to send email

```
$email = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail(); 
$email->setFrom("email@xxxx.com", "XXX Support");
$email->setSubject("XXXX.com - Password recovery for XXXXX");
$email->addTo("email@gmail.com", "Tester");
$email->addContent("text/plain", "Password recovery for XXXX");
$email->addContent(
    "text/html", $html
);
```

I retrieve my HTML file as $html

```
file_get_contents('https://xxxx.com/sendgrid-php/pwd.html');
```

The original HTML file contains CSS, it looks good but it appears only text with white background. In the HTML file I replace " with ' but it still not working.

Comment: Can you show an example of the HTML and CSS? Is the CSS inline within the HTML file, or in a separate file? It would need to be inline within a `<style>` tag. Also please bear in mind that email clients unfortunately do not generally adhere to the same standards as browsers when it comes to displaying HTML. They are inconsistent in their behaviour compared to each other, less sophisticated and often do not support all the same features. Testing the HTML in a browser via a regular HTML page is not a good test of how it will appear in an email.

Comment: The html-email tag right here on this site actually has a reasonably good basic intro to the topic: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/html-email/info

Comment: Please have a look here, http://co-miner.net/html.html

Comment: No, post the relevant information here please - otherwise your question can be closed as off-topic, as per [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (item 1). Your question is supposed to stand the test of time to help other readers in future, not just you right now. If the question relies too much on external links for it to make sense, it may become un-usuable in the future if those links change, or are removed, or the content of them is modified. Thanks.

Comment: Also what does `In the HTML file I replace " with '` mean? Where did you do that exactly? And for what purpose? Does the example you're going to show us contain that change, or is it the original version? Try to be clear and precise.

Comment: Also, show a screenshot of how the email appears when you receive it, and tell us whch email clients you have tested it with, and whether the result was consistent in each one.

Comment: I mean, I replace double quote in the HTML file with single quote because I just afraid that it may create a problem when put the content into an email

Comment: What information did you use to decide that it might cause a problem? That sounds like a bit of random guesswork, to be honest. Did you read it from somewhere reputable?

Comment: It appear like this http://co-miner.net/rpt.jpg

Comment: https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/email-development-best-practices-2/ is another good introductory guide to building HTML email which works.

Comment: The important part of that link being **Use Inline Styles** `Some Gmail clients, like Gmail Android App for Non-Gmail Accounts (GANGA), still don’t support embedded styles. In addition to this, there are a few smaller email clients like Yandex and Telstra that still require inline styles.`

Comment: Before I do this HTML email, I got one already which works fine. But I didn't work with sending email for a long time ago, I have seen that I have replaced a double quote with a single quote. This time it not works same as before because the version of my Linux server has been changed and the SendGrid code also have to change.

What should cause the problem? Maybe my PHP code?

Comment: Thanks, Adyson, I will give it a try on that resource. Thanks Riggs

Comment: Your PHP code is irrelevant. The issue will be in how the mail client interprets the HTML and CSS. As all the guides say, first you should test the mail on as many email clients as you can get hold of (most of them are free), so you can narrow the issue down to (hopefully) just one or two clients. Then you can research what those clients do / don't support and adjust your HTML to suit that. It may be that you need to simplify your CSS and HTML, and/or change the doctype, and/or use more inline styles, etc.

Comment: In short, do some actual research and testing instead of applying random changes which you used years ago - and which probably had nothing to do with any of your current issues.

Comment: Thank you, I will firstly try adjust my HTML

Answer (score 0):

you can not use separated css file for html e-mail, you have to write it inline.
so try to add inline css in your mail template and response it.

Comment: yes, I put CSS on the HTML file, please have a look here http://co-miner.net/html.html

Comment: i think may be your mail viewer not allow html mail, with mailer plugins, you usually need 2 version of the mail, 1 for html, and 1 for text only

i tried your html send by sendgrid and recieve and view on gmail, watch the link below
https://prnt.sc/12vhunl

Comment: and i think you can try adding all inline css to html tags, instead of using `<style>` tag in `<head>`

Comment: It is a mailchimp template. The styles are fine in the head of the document. Mailchimp compiler makes those styles inline by itself